# Styling Combobox and Button in ttk

Tags: python, tkinter, fonts, themes

I've run into an issue:

- If I want to change font of Combobox widget it has to go through `.configure(font=new_font)`, it doesn't care about value from `.configure(style='big.TCombobox')`(or similar, just an example)
- If I want to change font on Button widget then I cannot use `font` keyword in `.configure()` because it is not known to Tcl interpreter

My question: is there unified way of changing fonts across ttk widgets?
I would expect that on the image below font size of both comboboxes would be the same, given example code below, but they're not. And the only way to style button is through `ttk.Style` which does not work on combobox.

[image: incorrect font sizes]

Example with small setup and combinations presented:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import font

# setup example
window = Tk("Test")
root = ttk.Frame(window)
style = ttk.Style()
ttk.Label(root, text="Font keyword").grid(column=1, row=0)
ttk.Label(root, text="Font using Style").grid(column=2, row=0)
ttk.Label(root, text="TCombobox").grid(column=0, row=1)
ttk.Label(root, text="TButton").grid(column=0, row=2)

# setup font and styles
font_default = font.nametofont('TkDefaultFont')
font_big = font_default.copy()
# create bigger font based on default one
font_big.config(size=14, weight='bold')
# create font dict to embed this value into default values
# on my PC this gives for example '{Segoe UI} 14 bold'
font_dict = {'font': f'{{{font_big.actual()['family']}}} {font_big.actual()['size']} {font_big.actual()['weight']}'}

default_cb_style_dict = style.configure('TCombobox')
default_cb_style_dict.update(font_dict)
style.configure('big.TCombobox', **default_cb_style_dict)

default_btn_style_dict = style.configure('TButton')
default_btn_style_dict.update(font_dict)
style.configure('big.TButton', **default_btn_style_dict)


cb_font_kw = ttk.Combobox(root, values=list(map(str, range(3))), font=font_big)
cb_font_kw.grid(column=1, row=1)

# why this does not work?
cb_styled = ttk.Combobox(root, values=list(map(str, range(3))), style='big.TCombobox')
cb_styled.grid(column=2, row=1)

# label shows exception that would be otherwise thrown by trying to instantiate 'btn_font_kw'
ttk.Label(root, text='_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-font"').grid(column=1, row=2)
# btn_font_kw = ttk.Button(root, text='OK', font=font_big)
# btn_font_kw.grid(column=0, row=2)

# while this works perfectly fine?
btn_styled = ttk.Button(root, text='OK', style='big.TButton', command= lambda: breakpoint())
btn_styled.grid(column=2, row=2)

root.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is either a bug in Tk itself or somewhere deep in tkinter. After scouring the internet for answers and testing multiple other approaches I found this:

https://bugs.python.org/issue21341

It's almost 10 years old bug and I don't believe it will ever get resolved. Since Combobox internally uses Entry widget it's also affected.